# EXCEL: compute result of competition pool

Tags: excel

I want to have the results of handball pool in excel.
Entry table is:

```
    D  +   E    +   G    +   H    +   I
-------+--------+--------+--------+--------
       | Team A | Team B | Team C | Team D
-------+--------+--------+--------+--------
Team A |        | 21-12  | 12-3   | 25-26
Team B | 21-14  |        | 15-41  | 25-12
Team C | 14-7   |        |        | 10-29
Team D |        | 11-12  | 12-16  |
```

If the table is full (e.g. results in form x-y in each cell), the following formulas work:
- Number of goals by team A (as in colomn E):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VALUE(LEFT(E12:E15, FIND("-",E12:E15)-1)))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(E12:E15<>""),VALUE(LEFT(E12:E15, FIND("-",E12:E15)-1)))
```

But if some cells of the colum are empty it does not work.
Can you help me here?

Same issue with:

1. Number of goals against Team A (as in column E)

=SUMPRODUCT(--(E12:E15<>""),VALUE(MID(E12:E15, FIND("-",E12:E15)+1,99)))

2. Number of games won (as in column E)

=SUMPRODUCT(--(E12:E15<>""),--(LEFT(E12:E15, FIND("-",E12:E15)-1)

3. Number of games lost (as in column E)

=SUMPRODUCT(--(E12:E15<>""),--(LEFT(E12:E15, FIND("-",E12:E15)-1)>MID(E12:E15, FIND("-",E12:E15)+1,99)))

Thank you,
Chris.

Answer (score 4):

For E12:E16 two array formulas which require CSE,

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-", E12:E15)), --LEFT(E12:E15, FIND("-", E12:E15)-1)))
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-", E12:E15)), --MID(E12:E15, FIND("-", E12:E15)+1, 9)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using ISBLANK.

There might be unprintable characters in your blank cells, like the one enclosed here " " which is a blank, or say a carriage return of which two are enclosed here "

"  These may not be found by testing for "".

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your propositions.
I used your logic to build my own formulas.

Goals:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--(B6:B11<>""),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-",B6:B11)),VALUE(LEFT(B6:B11,FIND("-",B6:B11)-1)),0))}
```

Goals against:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--(B6:B11<>""),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-",B6:B11)),VALUE(MID(B6:B11,FIND("-",B6:B11)+1,99)),0))}
```

Games won:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B6:B11<>""),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-",B6:B11)),--(LEFT(B6:B11,FIND("-",B6:B11)-1)>MID(B6:B11,FIND("-",B6:B11)+1,99)),0))
```

Games lost:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--(B6:B11<>""),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-",B6:B11)),--(LEFT(B6:B11,FIND("-",B6:B11)-1)<MID(B6:B11,FIND("-",B6:B11)+1,99)),0))}
```

...
I did that by columns then by rows. (As it was to tricky to do both at the same time :-)

Adding colums & rows, I summarized all results in a single table.

Chris.